# Change default storage location of new shapefile

Tags: qgis, default

Is it possible to change the automatic placing to another place?

- When I create a new layer nearly all the time I fill name/geometritype/fieldname/and so on then OK
- And it says fail:permission denied, probably because the program is trying to save the files to a strange place.

Then I have to repeat everything and remember to press the button with the three dots.

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit Qgis 3.16.11

How do I change the predetermined place to the desktop?

[image]

Comment: If you don't specify a file name/path, you can't click `OK`, it is deactivated. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: OK, you mean how to change the default path for saving data (layers) - would have been clearer to ask it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Menu Settings > Options > System > Environment` and check the box `Use custom variables`. Then change variables like `HOME`, `HOMEPATH` or `USERPROFILE` to the path you whish:

[image]

Comment: Thanks do you which one? I have kind of the same as you C:\Users\"my computername" but when I click on the three dots it starts at "C:\Windows\System32" which is where I think its trying to save the files, there are no paths that have that text?

Comment: Try - I'm not sure which one, I was just checking the ones that have the path used by QGIS to store Shapefiles by default

Comment: the closest is the path for "ComSpec" which is C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe is that the one that should be changed?

Comment: Indeed - If you change `ComSpec`, files will be saved to `C:\Users\[Username]\Documents` - but not the path you set there. For this you probably have to change variables like HOME, HOMEPATH or USERPROFILE as mentioned in the answer. Did not it test it, however.